# Mac-Excel Conditional Formatting with 8 variables, any 2 combined variables give 2 outcomes

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos-catalina

MacOS Catalina,
MS Excel 16.40

I have a question, if anyone can help...(changed the request a bit because as I have been trying to do this myself, I couldn't get my head around it.
I have 8 variables. Name1,2,3,4,5,6,7,Name8.

Anything above 1.01 is worth 2 points. Anything below 0.99 is worth 1 point.
1.00 is considered as neutral.
The range I am dealing with is 1.00 as neutral/break even. Minimum is 0.00. Maximum is 2.00.
For Name1,3,5,7..
Anything from 2.00 to 1.01 is worth 2 points.
Anything from 0.99 to 0.00 is worth 1 point.
For Name2,4,6,8..
Anything from 2.00 to 1.01 is worth -2 points.
Anything from 0.99 to 0.00 is worth -1 point.

And so,for example

IF Name1 is 1.01 or greater then the cell color is GREEN and it is worth 2 points.

If Name2 is 0.99 or less then the cell color is RED and it worth -1 point.
Continuing...
And if Name1 and Name2 = 2 points and -1 point, then the sum is worth 1 point (2-1) and the cell color is GREEN and shows UP sign.

And
if Name3 and Name4 are 1 point and and -2 points, then the sum cell is RED, -1 point, and shows DOWN sign.

I would like to do this in excel.
I hope this is a better mock up.
[image]

Answer to Reddy
[image]

E1 is:
=IF(D1>=1,01;2; IF(D1=1;1;-1))

E3 is:
=IF(D3>=1,01;2; IF(D3=1;1;-1))

(I have not edited the other ones but my biggest problem is last 3 that should be on "WAIT" status)

F123 is:
=IF(E1+E3>0;"UP";IF(E1+E3<=0;"DOWN";"WAIT"))

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: I dont know how much clearer than this can I write it. I am more or less a beginner in Excel and I am struggling to make it work. I want to set this up in Excel using Conditional Formatting. If you can help, then please help. If you dont want to help then please leave my question alone to someone that is willing to help.

Comment: @Tine, the issue here is that there are some rules for submitting to SU. One of them includes showing that you have at least tried to solve the problem yourself. This is to discourage people from using those who answer questions here to do their work for them. If you could add some screenshots to your post that show the source data and a mockup of your intended outcome as well as an attempt at creating the conditional formatting, you will get better help.

Comment: I see. Thank you Flex. I understand. The thing is that I cant find any simple explanation to my excel problem. All are very sophisticated and I am just wondering if I can have something as simple as I am asking for. To be honest, I am stuck at where the cell would say Yes or no based on the colored with a number cell.

Comment: The mock up would definitely help as I can't visualize your the results you are looking for from the text.

Comment: Hi Brad, I am a bit new at this. Can you explain the mock up? So I can prepare better.

Comment: I edited my question and attached, hopefully, a better mock up. It is all just inserted numbers with no formulas behind it. Just to show what the end result I would like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is for Name 1 and 2, but you can adapt it for the others as the process is the same. This is done on a Windows machine (I think the process should be the same on a Mac).

You need to create 3 conditional formatting rules. Select both cells, click on Conditional Formatting -> New Rule. Select "Format only cells that contain".

- 1st rule: Cell Value between 1.01 and 2. Format the cell in green.
- 2nd rule: Cell Value between 0 and 0.99. Format the cell in red.
- 3rd rule: Cell Value between 1 and 1 (or cell value equal to 1). Format the cell in white.

***1st Rule***

[image: IMG:]

***2nd Rule***

[image: IMG:]

***3rd Rule***

[image: IMG:]

In E1 enter the formula,

```
=IF(D1>=1.01,2,IF(D1=1,1,1))
```

In E3, enter the formula:

```
=IF(D3>=1.01,-2,IF(D3=1,1,-1))
```

In F1, enter the formula. Merge the cells F3 to F5

```
=IF(OR(D1=1,D3=1),"WAIT",IF(E1+E3>0,"UP",IF(E1+E3=0,"WAIT","DOWN")))
```

The result will be like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Reddy!!! This is fantastic. 
Yea, Win or Mac are a bit different. There are few differences.I encountered few problems. In the screenshot you will see, I wrote on the outside what the result should be. And Wha the insides is telling me. I will attach the screenshot above.

Comment: @Tine I have the adjustments. You noticed that I forgot the `=` on my previous formula. The formulae are based mostly on your 1st screenshot + the last 3 example of the 2nd screenshot. If example 3 & 4 of your 2nd image are based on my previous formula, then they are wrong.

Comment: Thank you!!! Yes. I noticed Windows MS uses "." and ",". I have to use "," and ";" (on iMac MS) Formula works perfectly. Sincerely thank you again for solving my problem.